# VS 2013: Error loading CRM solution: Some properties could not be read

Tags: plugins, visual-studio-2013, dynamics-crm, projects-and-solutions

When trying to open a CRM solution in VS 2013, I get this error "**Some of the properties associated with the solution could not be read**". Below is my .sln. Could someone help?

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 2013
VisualStudioVersion = 12.0.40629.0
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "KTL.SalesOrderPlugin", "KTL.SalesOrderPlugin.csproj", "{D36890EC-F471-4332-8920-0C4FBF1FB3FA}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(CRMSolutionProperties) = preSolution
        SolutionIsBoundToCRM = TRUE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {D36890EC-F471-4332-8920-0C4FBF1FB3FA}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {D36890EC-F471-4332-8920-0C4FBF1FB3FA}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {D36890EC-F471-4332-8920-0C4FBF1FB3FA}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {D36890EC-F471-4332-8920-0C4FBF1FB3FA}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've installed the [Microsoft Dynamics Developer Toolkit](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DynamicsCRMPG.MicrosoftDynamicsCRMDeveloperToolkit). The following section indicates that the solution was created using it:

```
GlobalSection(CRMSolutionProperties) = preSolution
    SolutionIsBoundToCRM = TRUE
EndGlobalSection
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I just installed VS 2012 with the SDK toolkit and tried again, and it worked.